# What is the lower $n$ such that $\mathbb{CP}^4$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, mathematical-physics

It is well known that $\mathbb{CP}^4$ cannot be embedded in a
Euclidean space of dimension 11 or less.

Similarly, at [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581683/can-mathbb-c-p4-be-smoothly-embedded-in-mathbb-r12?rq=1)  was proved that:

$\mathbb{CP}^4$ does not immerse into $\mathbb{R}^{12}$.

For other side at [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041542/how-to-prove-that-cp4-cannot-be-immersed-in-r11) was proved that:

$\mathbb{CP}^4$ does not immerse into $\mathbb{R}^{13}$.

My question now is:  What is the lower $n$ such that $\mathbb{CP}^4$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: $\Bbb {CP}^4$ is a closed orientable manifold of dimension $m=8$, therefore it can be embedded in $\Bbb R^{2m-1}=\Bbb R^{15}$. The only thing left is whether or not it can be embedded in $\Bbb R^{14}$.

Comment: The answer to the first question shows $\mathbb{CP}^4$ cannot immerse in $\mathbb{R}^{14}$, so the lowest $n$ is $15$.

Comment: Where in the world did you get the differential forms tag? Please don't use irrelevant tags.